# Как выровнять по-вертикали контент внутри ::before?

Tags: html, css

Как можно выровнять контент (счетчик) внутри ::Before?

Вот как нужно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что у меня имеется:

```css
body {
  width: 920px;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 920px;
  counter-reset: numbers;
}

li {
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  counter-increment: pages;
  position: relative;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #cccccc
}

li:before {
  content: counter(pages);
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  background-color: #ff5353;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::before {
  background-color: #cc4242;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Государственная регистрация интегрирует равновероятный коносамент, таким образом сбылась мечта идиота - утверждение полностью доказано. Отчуждение естественно ускоряет интеграл Фурье. Банкротство страхует словесный индоссамент, что и требовалось доказать.<br>    Последнее векторное равенство, как бы это ни казалось парадоксальным, астатически продолжает серийный период. Электромеханическая система использует хроматический октавер. Угол крена методически варьирует угол тангажа. Электромеханическая система,
    согласно уравнениям Лагранжа, возможна. Исключая малые величины из уравнений, гармонический интервал монотонно дает конструктивный крен.</li>
  <li>Одиннадцатисложник интуитивно понятен. В соответствии с общим принципом, установленным Конституцией РФ, парафраз переворачивает предел функции. Если выстроить в ряд случаи инверсий у Державина, то оферта гарантирует обязательственный договор, что известно
    даже школьникам.</li>
  <li>Математическая статистика, как можно доказать с помощью не совсем тривиальных допущений, ускоряет платежный документ. Умысел гарантирует натуральный логарифм. Число е, в первом приближении, дает экстремум функции, учитывая недостаточную теоретическую
    проработанность этой отрасли права.</li>
  <li>Дифференциальное уравнение, в согласии с традиционными представлениями, иллюстрирует Указ. Замысел аннигилирует изоморфный одиннадцатисложник. Продолжая до бесконечности ряд 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 и т.д., имеем лексика бесконтрольно
    развивает резкий интеграл от функции, обращающейся в бесконечность вдоль линии.</li>
  <li>Ложная цитата детерменирована. Многочлен поручает анапест, что и требовалось доказать. Скалярное произведение выбирает императивный ортогональный определитель. Договор предоставляет невероятный математический анализ. Нежилое помещение абсурдно упорядочивает
    незаконный субъект.</li>
  <li>Реакция интегрирует интеллект. Анима, несмотря на внешние воздействия, осознаёт контраст. Волчок безусловно отталкивает конфликтный эскапизм. Инсайт требует перейти к поступательно перемещающейся системе координат, чем и характеризуется конфликтный
    гироинтегратор. Управление полётом самолёта известно.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если пустует второй псевдоэлемент, то используйте его:

```css
body {
  width: 920px;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 920px;
  counter-reset: numbers;
}

li {
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  counter-increment: pages;
  position: relative;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #cccccc
}

li:before {
  content: counter(pages);
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  width: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -9px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff5353;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

li:nth-child(odd):after {
  background-color: #cc4242;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Государственная регистрация интегрирует равновероятный коносамент, таким образом сбылась мечта идиота - утверждение полностью доказано. Отчуждение естественно ускоряет интеграл Фурье. Банкротство страхует словесный индоссамент, что и требовалось доказать.<br>    Последнее векторное равенство, как бы это ни казалось парадоксальным, астатически продолжает серийный период. Электромеханическая система использует хроматический октавер. Угол крена методически варьирует угол тангажа. Электромеханическая система,
    согласно уравнениям Лагранжа, возможна. Исключая малые величины из уравнений, гармонический интервал монотонно дает конструктивный крен.</li>
  <li>Одиннадцатисложник интуитивно понятен. В соответствии с общим принципом, установленным Конституцией РФ, парафраз переворачивает предел функции. Если выстроить в ряд случаи инверсий у Державина, то оферта гарантирует обязательственный договор, что известно
    даже школьникам.</li>
  <li>Математическая статистика, как можно доказать с помощью не совсем тривиальных допущений, ускоряет платежный документ. Умысел гарантирует натуральный логарифм. Число е, в первом приближении, дает экстремум функции, учитывая недостаточную теоретическую
    проработанность этой отрасли права.</li>
  <li>Дифференциальное уравнение, в согласии с традиционными представлениями, иллюстрирует Указ. Замысел аннигилирует изоморфный одиннадцатисложник. Продолжая до бесконечности ряд 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 и т.д., имеем лексика бесконтрольно
    развивает резкий интеграл от функции, обращающейся в бесконечность вдоль линии.</li>
  <li>Ложная цитата детерменирована. Многочлен поручает анапест, что и требовалось доказать. Скалярное произведение выбирает императивный ортогональный определитель. Договор предоставляет невероятный математический анализ. Нежилое помещение абсурдно упорядочивает
    незаконный субъект.</li>
  <li>Реакция интегрирует интеллект. Анима, несмотря на внешние воздействия, осознаёт контраст. Волчок безусловно отталкивает конфликтный эскапизм. Инсайт требует перейти к поступательно перемещающейся системе координат, чем и характеризуется конфликтный
    гироинтегратор. Управление полётом самолёта известно.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развитие моего мышления )

Comment: Не за что. Можно было еще несколько подобных решений придумать, если бы `:after` был занят. Например, при помощи `border-left`. Выровнять текст внутри псевдоэлемента вам не удастся.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с использованием `display:flex`

```css
body {
  width: 920px;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 920px;
  counter-reset: numbers;
}

li {
  padding-top: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  counter-increment: pages;
  position: relative;
}

li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #cccccc
}

li:before {
  content: counter(pages);
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
  background-color: #ff5353;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li:nth-child(odd)::before {
  background-color: #cc4242;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Государственная регистрация интегрирует равновероятный коносамент, таким образом сбылась мечта идиота - утверждение полностью доказано. Отчуждение естественно ускоряет интеграл Фурье. Банкротство страхует словесный индоссамент, что и требовалось доказать.<br>    Последнее векторное равенство, как бы это ни казалось парадоксальным, астатически продолжает серийный период. Электромеханическая система использует хроматический октавер. Угол крена методически варьирует угол тангажа. Электромеханическая система,
    согласно уравнениям Лагранжа, возможна. Исключая малые величины из уравнений, гармонический интервал монотонно дает конструктивный крен.</li>
  <li>Одиннадцатисложник интуитивно понятен. В соответствии с общим принципом, установленным Конституцией РФ, парафраз переворачивает предел функции. Если выстроить в ряд случаи инверсий у Державина, то оферта гарантирует обязательственный договор, что известно
    даже школьникам.</li>
  <li>Математическая статистика, как можно доказать с помощью не совсем тривиальных допущений, ускоряет платежный документ. Умысел гарантирует натуральный логарифм. Число е, в первом приближении, дает экстремум функции, учитывая недостаточную теоретическую
    проработанность этой отрасли права.</li>
  <li>Дифференциальное уравнение, в согласии с традиционными представлениями, иллюстрирует Указ. Замысел аннигилирует изоморфный одиннадцатисложник. Продолжая до бесконечности ряд 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31 и т.д., имеем лексика бесконтрольно
    развивает резкий интеграл от функции, обращающейся в бесконечность вдоль линии.</li>
  <li>Ложная цитата детерменирована. Многочлен поручает анапест, что и требовалось доказать. Скалярное произведение выбирает императивный ортогональный определитель. Договор предоставляет невероятный математический анализ. Нежилое помещение абсурдно упорядочивает
    незаконный субъект.</li>
  <li>Реакция интегрирует интеллект. Анима, несмотря на внешние воздействия, осознаёт контраст. Волчок безусловно отталкивает конфликтный эскапизм. Инсайт требует перейти к поступательно перемещающейся системе координат, чем и характеризуется конфликтный
    гироинтегратор. Управление полётом самолёта известно.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: лови плюс за хороший ответ. От автора вопроса видимо не дождешься, даже после явных намёков, что принято благодарить чекбоксами и плюсами за потраченное время и полезный ответ